# How to disable custom URLs in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2

I hate the codeigniter custom urls where it's: domain.com/controller/action/id

How can I have it like a normal website like: domain.com/controller.php

Anyone know how to disable that?

(using the latest codeigniter)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I'm trying to parse my php _GET queries, but the php functions can't read them properly. I also have a lot of function that parse urls, but they don't work with the custom codeigniter urls. I'm just trying to have a traditional url structure.

Comment: Perhaps an MVC framework isn't the right choice? It seems like it might create a lot of extra work for you. You could look into [custom routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and also enabling `GET` parameters (which *is* possible with CI).

Comment: I really like the MVC framework, but I just think their urls are messed up imo. Some people don't care about SEO, like me. Yeah, I saw the routing page, doesn't really help. I'm just trying to convert controllers to php pages like so: domain.com/main.php (controller is main)

Comment: I wouldn't consider them "messed up", but they might be different from what you're used to. Honestly, I'd suggest embracing them if you're set on using CodeIgniter, rather than fighting against the convention. Just my 0.02

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm not sure how having a file extension gets you any more SEO juice.  w3c recommends not including it in the url (see: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI, specifically the "What to leave out" section).  You will probably be able to do what you want, but will have to use some kind of URL rewriting with apache.

Comment: you can parse GET just fine in codeigniter... have you tried domain.com/controller/action?id=123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hate it, you might be not ready to jump in a framework like codeigniter. Rest like urls are a big feature, so the url has some actually meaning, and not just a pointer for something. It's ok if you are used to something like `example.com/person.php?id=123&action=seeprofile`, instead of `example.com./person/profile/123` but how can't you see the beauty of it? You just should check out some experts explaining why you should do it like that, and why everyone else are doing it like that.

EDIT:
You should check this pages of the docs, so you can understand the neat of this great feature.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: +1 for "If you hate it, you might be not ready to jump in a framework like codeigniter."

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could use: `domain.com/file.php?id=34&action=now&mode=delete` ? (assuming file is a class)

Comment: @user962449: You could set that up any number of ways, but the convention goes like this `domain.com/controller_name/method_name/argument_1/argument_2/etc`. Keep in mind that the [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) and [Routing capabilities](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) help make this a very flexible approach.

Comment: How would you know what goes where? Like, what argument is what.

Comment: added some references that will help you understand what's going on

Answer (score 1):

from the CI documentation:  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Adding a URL Suffix

In your config/config.php file you can specify a suffix that will be added to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter. For example, if a URL is this:

example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes
You can optionally add a suffix, like .html, making the page appear to be of a certain type:

example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes.html

Comment: That doesn't work because if I want to have domain.com/main.php I would have to use domain.com/index.php?c=main instead.

Comment: sorry you're right, if you take the .php file out of the application then you can serve it up as yoursite.com/outside.php. If you want to make calls to your app's DB in outside.php, you just need to do the typical PHP code, e.g., `mysql_connect(servername,username,password);` to connect to it.

Comment: do you mean you'd still like to "use" your app or just the CI syntax? if latter, then i echo ismaelga's answer. If former, then just use regular php to connect to your app.

Comment: I want to use the CI syntax and framework, just not the url structure to access the classes and methods.

Comment: I'm kinda new to CI, but this removing of the ".php" seems like an issue a real CI afficinado would know since its such a fundamental feature of CI. Maybe pose your question on codeigniter forums? I've gotten some pretty sophisticated help there sometimes. There's gotta be a hack for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You may say you 'hate the custom urls' but this actually is a fundamental part of how the framework .. works.

If you really do not like them, then you need to investigate [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), and how this works in the codeigniter context. There is a really, really good argument for **not** using the controller method id pattern, which I would also support, but this is not it. Internationalisation, for just one thing.

Anyway, adding file.php or my-pro-script.php to the domain name is totally irrelevant for us, the users of your site, who couldn't care less about the .php extension. What's your argument for wanting to do this?

Comment: my app will contain a lot of reports and searches. That's I need the urls to be as basic as possible. It's more work with the custom structure imo. CI suppose to cut coding time not increase it...

Comment: Also, do you know where I could find more examples on routing? (besides the link you provided).

Comment: ok, I think I understand what you want to achieve - routing here is definitely the answer. I was investigating a similar kind of idea for implementing translatable URLs, and a really nice solution is this one: http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/06/dynamic-routing-from-database-in-codeigniter/ - basically, you define custom routes through some kind of DB backend, and CI will use any routes it finds defined instead of the URL pattern you mention in your question. Take a look. But - you really need to think a bit more about 'simplicity' and what it means in terms of your site.

Answer (score 0):

There is option **enable_query_strings** in the config.php file,
may be that's what you want...
You can enable standard query string based URLs by setting this option to TRUE.